# *this Error in C++

Tags: c++, boolean, this, user-defined-functions

I am trying to compare and see if an implicit parameter is greater than the explicit parameter of a function.  When doing this it says that using `*this` is invalid because it can only be used inside a nonstatic member function and I'm not sure why it is giving me this error nor how to fix it. Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
bool isGreaterThan(English_length&L)
{
    if (*this > L)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Here is my class header:

```
class English_length 
{
   public:

    //------------------------------------------------------
    //----- Constructors -----------------------------------
    //------------------------------------------------------

        //---------------------------------- 
        // default constructor --
        // initializes a newly created length 
        // to zero
        //---------------------------------- 
        English_length() ; 

    //------------------------------------------------------
    //----- Inspectors -------------------------------------
    //------------------------------------------------------

        //---------------------------------- 
        // returns inches "left over" (0-11)
        //---------------------------------- 
        int inches() const ;

        //---------------------------------- 
        // returns total inches in measurement:
        // 2 feet 3 inches returns 27
        //---------------------------------- 
        int totalInches() const ;

        //---------------------------------- 
        // returns feet "left over" (0-2)
        //---------------------------------- 
        int feet() const ;

        //---------------------------------- 
        // returns total feet in measurement:
        // 1 yard 2 feet 3 inches returns 5
        //---------------------------------- 
        int totalFeet() const ;

        //---------------------------------- 
        // returns total yards
        //---------------------------------- 
        int yards() const ;

    //------------------------------------------------------
    //----- Mutators ---------------------------------------
    //------------------------------------------------------

        //---------------------------------- 
        // increases the length of the measure by amt_to_add
        //---------------------------------- 
        void add_inches(int amt_to_add) ;

    //------------------------------------------------------
    //----- Facilitators -----------------------------------
    //------------------------------------------------------

        //---------------------------------- 
        // return EnglishLength in string form:
        // "x yards, y feet, and z inches"
        //---------------------------------- 
        string toString() const ; 
        bool isGreaterThan(English_length & L);
private:
    int inches_; // 0-11
    int feet_;   // 0-2
    int yards_;  // > 0
};
```

Comment: Functions only have an implicit parameter when they're non-static member functions. They need to know the instance. What would `this` be otherwise?

Comment: What makes a function nonstatic? Isn't my function nonstatic?

Comment: Please provide more details about your `English_length` class - perhaps even post its header.

Comment: @user3403855: You forgot the most important half of chris' sentence.

Comment: @user3403855 It's non-static, yet it's also a non-member (i.e. "free-standing").

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But in my header file it is apart of my class.  So wouldn't that make it a member function?

Comment: The code has excessive comments! :-)

Comment: @user3403855, If that was assumed for your definition, there would be no way to create a free function with the same name and signature as one in a class. Two classes sharing the same one would cause problems if you wanted to define both outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Since `isGreaterThan` is a member function of the class, you need to define it like:

```
bool English_length::isGreaterThan(English_length&L)
{
    if (*this > L)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: That takes care of that but now it throws an error when i use the greater than sign to compare the two.

Comment: Not sure what your method of comparing two objects are. The compiler does not provides a default `operator>` function. You have to implement that function if you want to use `*this > L`. On the other hand, if you want to just compare the addresses the objects, you can change that test to `this > &L`.

Comment: @user3403855 in your case you would probably want to compare the totalInches by using `totalInches() > L.totalInches()`

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer to the instance of a class.

```
class Foo
{
   void Instance() { *this; } // Yep, this has been instanced.
   static void Static() { *this; } // Nope, method is static.
}

Foo f; // Instance of class Foo

void Global() { *this; } // Nope, not associated with a class instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
bool isGreaterThan(English_length&L)
```

need to change to

```
bool English_length::isGreaterThan(English_length&L)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then, there need to be a proper implementation of the method. There are two options: (1) implement `operator>()` as in the present form of the code, but which is missing as reported by the compiler, OR (2) implement in terms of another available method, `total_inches()`. Following is an illustration of option #2.

```
bool English_length::isGreaterThan( English_length const & rhs ) {
    return total_inches() > rhs.total_inches();
}
```

Comment: That works! but now its throwing an error saying I can't use the > sign to compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the function outside the class definition the following way

```
bool English_length::isGreaterThan(English_length&L)
{
    if (*this > L)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

However the function has no any sense because there is no `operator >` in the class definition.

Comment: So then how would I see if the implicit parameter is greater than the explicit parameter of the function?

Comment: @user3403855 i do not know what is the criterion. It is you who should decide how to compare objects.